# How to install forexconnect in a PC running Linux

Tags: python-3.x, installation, module, linux-mint

I have just installed Linux Mint to my PC then Anaconda for Linux and then I tried to install the Python module forexconnect  (https://pypi.org/project/forexconnect/).

To make sure that python is added to my path I run the following commands:

```
~$ echo export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:~/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/" >> ~/.bash_profile
~$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then I run the command:

```
pip install --user forexconnect
```

I got an error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement forexconnect
ERROR: No matching distribution found for forexconnect
```

I also downloaded the forexconnect module from here:

```
https://github.com/gehtsoft/forex-connect
```

but I could not find a `setup.py` file to install forexconnect with the command:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=~
```

How can I install forexconnect to my PC running Linux Mint?

Answer (score 0):

The Python Forex Connect API works only with Python versions 3.5.x, 3.6.x and 3.7.x.
https://pypi.org/project/forexconnect/